# Alternative shorter method to permute and reshape a multidimensional-array

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, reshape, permute

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
a(:,:,1) =
    11    12    13
    21    22    23

a(:,:,2) =
    21    22    23
    31    32    33

a(:,:,3) =
    31    32    33
    41    42    43
```

The end result looks as follows:

```
e =
    11    21    31
    12    22    32
    13    23    33
    21    31    41
    22    32    42
    23    33    43
```

In order to obtain array e, I did the following:

```
b=permute(a,[2,1,3])  
c=reshape(b,1,6,[])  
d=permute(c,[2,1,3])
```

Is there a cleaner or more elegant way of achieving the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here permute used once:

```
b = permute(a,[2 1 3]);
result = reshape(b, [], 3)
```

Comment: I feel this answer fits my question best. Thanks to all for the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like the following:

```
reshape([a(:,:,1);a(:,:,2);a(:,:,3)].',6,3)
```